# How to pass a list of string to a javascript using Razor on ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to pass a list of strings from the server-side to be used on client-side. I'm using Razor and ASP.NET MVC.

In other part of my code, I could pass a list of integers. I declared a `List<int>` and returned inside a model to the view to be rendered. On the view, I could pass to the JavaScript in the following way:

```
var list = [ @string.Join(",", Model.Elements); ];
```

There is a way to pass a list of string (`List<string>`) in a similar way.

Note: I've tried in two ways:

First, I wrote
`var list = [ "@string.Join("\",\"" , Model.Elements)" ];`, but it rendered: `var list = [ "string1&quot;,&quot;string2" ];`.

Second, I wrote `var list = @JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Elements);`, but it rendered: `var list = [&quot;string1&quot;,&quot;string2&quot;`. In this way, I even tried to parse via `JSON.parse()` method but I got the error:

> Unexpected token & in JSON at position 1

Comment: If you `List<string>` property is named `Elements`, then you should create a javascript array using `var elements = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Elements))` and then you can use `var list = elements.join()` if you want a comma separated string

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm not sure in this day and age that I'd recommend `Json.Encode`.  I'd probably stick with a Newtonsoft (or other performant and edge-case inclusive serializer) approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I didn't find a question about it, so I posted this question.
I tested with the Newtonsoft method `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` instead of `Json.Encode()` and it worked perfectly.